# Importing realm changes in Keycloak 23

Tags: docker, keycloak

Hi I have an issue I was wondering if I could solve using only the Keycloak Docker image. The problem I am attempting to solve is that we have a realm on a lower environment that we wish to duplicate on a higher environment. Lets say that a developer team adds a client role, attribute or mapper on environment A, performs a partial export and then in environment B we add the `--import-realm` argument to `kc.sh start` and mount this exported json file to `/opt/keycloak/data/import`

The issue is that if the realm already exists the import will be skipped. Is there a way to "override/force" this re-import? Or will I need to use something like the `bitnami/keycloak-config-cli` image to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are are using the official KeyCloak Docker image then you should set the `migration.strategy` Java parameter to `OVERWRITE_EXISTING` (Default is `IGNORE_EXISTING` and this is the reason why skipped your import) in your Dockerfile/compose file.

**For example:**

```
KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/opt/keycloak/data/import/keycloak-realm.json
JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

**Import/Export reference:**

- [KeyCloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport)

**`migration.strategy` options:**

> -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy
>
> This property is used during import. It can be used to specify how to proceed if a realm with same name already exists in the database where you are going to import data. Possible values are:
>
> IGNORE_EXISTING - Ignore importing if a realm of this name already exists.
>
> OVERWRITE_EXISTING - Remove existing realm and import it again with new data from the JSON file. If you want to fully migrate one environment to another and ensure that the new environment will contain the same data as the old one, you can specify this.